# Azure B2C - disable 6 digit code verification on signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I've connected Azure B2C to Google OAuth, however it still requires the google user to enter a 6 digit code sent to their email address on sign up

Is it possible to turn the email verification off? It makes no sense to have it on with Google single sign-on

Comment: Have you followed [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-user-flow) while connecting Azure B2C to Google OAuth?

Comment: Yep, I've followed that document and got everything working, except for the 6 digit email verification that I can't seem to get rid of for Google OAuth sign ups

Comment: You can disable email verification using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/disable-email-verification?pivots=b2c-user-flow. However, it is not recommended due to security reasons.

Comment: Ahh yep, that's how I did it... it makes sense to disable it for Google single sign on, but not for email/password created accounts ... I'm hoping to be able to disable just for Google

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer - turns out I had to disable email verification on the "Email" attribute (it defaults to true)